# text alignment issue using 'altacv' using overleaf templet

Tags: overleaf, altacv

[image: The text under EXPERIENCE and ABOUT ME are not aligned.]

the code for the `EXPERIENCE` image is:

```
\cvsection{Experience}
\cvevent{Technical Manager}{Labkafe}{August 2018 -- January 2021}{Kolkata, India}
\begin{itemize}
\item Designed and developed scientific laboratory equipment
\item Led the quality testing team, built product packages and user manuals
\item Analised sales data and customer feedback on excel
\item Benchmarked installation time, generated leads, and increased sales by 35\% 
\item Trained professionals in scientific laboratory
\item Provided technical support to customers
\item Created tutorial series on YouTube
\item Installed Equipment and executed experiments on-site
\item Managed logistics and tracked product delivery information
\end{itemize}
```

and code for `ABOUT ME` is:

```
\cvsection[\marginpar{p1sidebar}]{About Me}
\begin{itemize}
I am a data enthusiast with hands-on experience in entry-level data analysis. I am proficient in Python (NumPy, Pandas, Matplotlib, Seaborn), Tableau, SQL (MySQL), MS Excel, Google spreadsheet. Targeting Data Analyst position in Spain with a strong desire to learn problem-solving skills. I have overall 8+ years of experience in teaching, software development, sales data analysis, and customer support.
\end{itemize}
```

**How to align those lines?**

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `\usepackage{ragged2e}` package and `\justifying` command. And it worked.

```
\cvsection{About Me}

\justifying % Use package `\usepackage{ragged2e}` in the preamble
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2pt, rightmargin=1pt]
I am a data enthusiast with hands-on experience in entry-level data analysis. I am proficient in Python (NumPy, Pandas, Matplotlib, Seaborn), Tableau, SQL (MySQL), MS Excel, Google spreadsheet. Targeting Data Analyst position in Spain with strong desire to learn problem-solving skills. I have overall 8+ years of experience in teaching, software development, sales data analysis and customer support
\end{itemize}
```